# add_image_sizes ignoring crop sizes and using proportion

Tags: images, cropping

Before we start, the image is definitely big enough.

I have an image that is 2206 x 2042 and I wish to crop (not scale) it in a number of different ways to be used responsively.

The sizes I am trying to produce are:

```
add_image_size( 'artist-full-xs', 730, 1842, array('right', 'bottom') );
add_image_size( 'artist-full-xs-sm', 730, 1000, array('right', 'bottom') );
add_image_size( 'artist-full-xs-sm-2', 730, 600, array('right', 'bottom') );
```

The first image crops as it is supposed to, the next two both scale instead of crop. This is found by looking in the uploads folder, nothing to do with any templating issues.

@Andy Macauley-Brook Actual sizes output are as follows:

730 x 1842
730 X 1000
730 X 600
So the actual cropping is working is just working proportionally for the last two instead of an actual crop

Does anyone know why and can possibly help me out?

Comment: What are the actual sizes that the three images end up as?

Comment: Please try to use same account, that will allow you to properly edit and discuss your own question. If you didn't mean to create multiple accounts you can request to merge them http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 8):

WordPress "crop" doesn't literally mean crop. As in take an image and cut out this precise portion of it from specified point.

What it roughly means is: resize image to fit as well as possible, then crop parts that don't fit. In effect this meant that results are affected by *ratio* both of source image and target size.

The exact logic is contained in `image_resize_dimensions()` function and summarize by inline comments as following:

```
// crop the largest possible portion of the original image that we can size to $dest_w x $dest_h
```

Not just *exact* portion, but *largest possible* portion of original.

The exact steps are math and aren't too friendly to briefly read and/or explain. From quick look what seems to happen is:

1. Ratio of original image is calculated.
2. How would it best fit onto target size is determined.
3. Crop applied on result of previous step.

In your specific case the difference between sizes is that first two are *tall* (larger height) and third one is *wide* (larger width).

- In former case the original is sized by *height*, then *left* part is cut off.
- In latter case the original is sized by *width*, then *top* part is cut off.

That what leads to sizes looking different. Because aspects ratios are different, WP fits original into them in different ways.

If you look at them side by side it's pretty visible how this logic got applied:

[image: wordpress image sizes crop]

Comment: I thought you could add a filter to `image_resize_dimensions` to bypass the scaling that WP does and get a real crop?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Would have to math coordinates stuff on your own though. :) Also I am not sure that's _really_ desirable in many cases. Smaller "real" crop out of large image can be pretty nonsensical.